# VBA Compare numbers and highlight if outside tolerance +/-.0005

Tags: excel, compare, vba

On a brand new Excel file, I want to use commandButton_click to see if any of the numbers are ouside my tolerance (example +/- 0.0005) 
IF any of the numbers are outside the tolerance, it should highlight the "wrong" cells (see picture). 
Update: If someone know how I can do that in Conditional Formatting please show me. Thank you very much!

[image: My Excel spreadsheet]

Comment: Do you currently have a command button and want to change the functionality, or is this entire thing something you want from scratch? Also, conditional formatting can do this sort of thing fairly easily with no VBA required.

Comment: Do you know "conditional formatting"? If you use that, and are careful to paste values (not format), then you don't actually need VBA

Comment: I'm open for any possible help. I don't know how to "compare" numbers with  a tolerance in conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a slight variation of @trincot 's idea. You can create a named range which stands for `tolerance` and then use that for greater readability. Note that you have to do this twice, once for the upper cells and once for the lower cells:

[image]

If you haven't used named ranges before, select the two cells (A4:B4 in the screenshot) which contain the tolerance and click `Create Names from Selection` on the Formulas tab.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and professional answer, it worked well!

Answer (score 1):

With conditional formatting you would do it as follows:

1. Select the cells in the range `A6:O7`
2. Click *Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule.*
3. In the *New Formatting Rule* dialog box, click *Use a formula to determine which cells to format.*
4. Under *Format values where this formula is true*, type the formula: `=ABS(A6-A1)>$D$4` (make sure the reference `$D$4` corresponds to where you have the tolerance input).
5. Click *Format*, and then choose the formatting options you want to apply to values which are outside the tolerance.
6. Click *OK* on all open dialogs.

You don't need the command button with this solution, as Excel will apply the formatting immediately. Just take care not to paste formatting, because then you will destroy the above configured conditional formatting. So only paste values.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and professional answer, it worked well!